# How do you get the username of someone who has filled in a form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

This must be incredibly simple, but I'm obviously missing something...

I'm using Identity for my user logic.

I've called my model "Post". It has 3 string properties: A title, a message and an author username

The code is failing to work, but the reason is obvious enough: The AuthorUsername is returning null, or empty.

This isn't a surprise, since I've not been able to figure out how to get the username of the poster.

I know about `_userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` but I don't have a clue where to put it...

My database saving logic begins with "If(!ModelState.IsValid){return View("Index")}", so I'd have to sort out the logic for getting the username before that... which would mean in the cshtml view.

I have confirmed by using a dummy value with `Html.Hidden("AuthorUserName", "SuperAdminTest")` that everything works just fine once that value is set.

It seems that whenever I try to add code, StackOverflow prevents me from posting this... so no code to post.

Comment: You can get the user name by doing `User.Identity.Name`, if you've setup `Asp.Net Identity` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The AuthorUsername is returning null, or empty.

To get the name of the current SignedIn user, as @DavidLiang mentioned in comment, you can use this code snippet `User.Identity.Name`. And the following sample code is for your reference.

```
@model Post

@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreatePost";
}

<h1>CreatePost</h1>

<h4>Post</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreatePost">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Message" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Message" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Message" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
            {
                @Html.Hidden("AuthorUserName", User.Identity.Name)
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.Hidden("AuthorUserName", "AnonymousUser")
            }
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Test Result

[image]

[image]

Comment: It was something obvious after all... can't believe I spent a couple hours being stuck over such a minor thing. How embarring. Oh well. you live and learn.